# How to change drag and drop item localstorage place?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a simple drag and drop system when an item is entered, it creates a localstorage object with the "value" key. If I replace this added item with the drag and drop event, a new localstorage element is created with the "other" key and it is saved there, but I want it to be deleted from the "value" section when the item is replaced. How can I achieve this? You can check the codepen demo for a trial. Codepen: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/ExNbZGo
// Above Code is only about localstorage full code is on codepen account

```
function getLocalStorage() {
    let value;
    if (localStorage.getItem('value') === null) {
        value = [];
    } else {
        value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("value"))
    }
    return value;
}

function addToLocalStorage(paragraph) {
    let value = getLocalStorage();
    value.push(paragraph);
    
    localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(value))
}

function changeAddToStorage(value) {
    localStorage.setItem("other", JSON.stringify(value))
}

function dragStart(element) {
    element.classList.add('draggable')
}

function dragEnd(element) {
    drags.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.classList.contains('box-2')) {
            changeAddToStorage(element.innerHTML)
        }
    })
    element.classList.remove('draggable')
}
```

Comment: Something like [`removeItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)?

Comment: Removeitem () does not delete a key directly? I want to delete the value in the key. For example, there is a key named "try" and there are 3 values like "1", "2", "3" and I want to apply the deletion for the value "2" that I drag and drop

Comment: Then just set it to null

Answer (score 0):

To remove the item from "value", call `localStorage.removeItem("value")` when the item is replaced.

```js
function changeAddToStorage(value) {
    localStorage.removeItem("value")   // remove "value"
    localStorage.setItem("other", JSON.stringify(value))  // save in "other"
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try ,mark it as solved if correct.

Comment: Removeitem () does not delete a key directly? I want to delete the value in the key. For example, there is a key named "try" and there are 3 values like "1", "2", "3" and I want to apply the deletion for the value "2" that I drag and drop

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Perhaps another community member will be able to help. Best of luck.